# find boundary co ordinates of image in matlab

Tags: matlab, coordinates, boundary

I want to find boundary points (co-ordinates) of hand contour in **counter-clockwise** manner in matlab. i.e. starting from any point traverse counter-clockwise and store co-ordinates.

Simple row column scanning is not useful as the co-ordinates has to be 8-connected.

[image]

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

You can use `imcontour` to get the contour, and then `fliplr` to arrange it counter-clockwise.

With your image:

```
I = imread('Image.jpg');

% --- Get a BW image, remove the title
BW = rgb2gray(I)<200;
BW(1:50,:) = 0;

% With a logical image, simply use:
% BW = double(Img);

% --- Find the outer contour coordinates
BW = imfill(BW, 'holes');
C = imcontour(BW,1);

% --- Arrange the contour counter-clockwise
x = fliplr(C(1,2:end));
y = fliplr(C(2,2:end));

% --- Display    
imshow(BW)
hold on
plot(x, y);

% --- Display regularly spaced markers to check the order
bin = linspace(1,numel(x), 11);
bin = round(bin(1:end-1));
cm = jet(numel(bin));
for i = 1:numel(bin)
    scatter(x(bin(i)), y(bin(i)), 'o', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'none', ...
        'MarkerFaceColor', cm(i,:));
    text(x(bin(i)), y(bin(i))+10, num2str(i), 'color', cm(i,:));
end
```

The contour is stored in the `x` and `y` vectors. The result is:

[image: Result]

Best,

Comment: Thanks a lot for solution. however If I want the co-ordinates of point selected from `bin = linspace(1,numel(x), 11);` Here 11 points are given. How do I get co-ordinates of these points? 

When used fliplr, I got points in clockwise manner, quite the opposite as you said.
`% --- Arrange the contour counter-clockwise
x = fliplr(C(1,2:end));
y = fliplr(C(2,2:end));`

Comment: The coordinates of the contour are in `x` and `y`, the part with `bin` is just for visualization purposes. And `fliplr` just flips the vector, so depending on your orientation you may or may not want to use it. If your vector is vertical you may want to use `flipud` instead. Is that clear ?

Comment: Got it. Thanks. One more thing, I am using source image I which is binary  not RGB. How do I modify this code to work with it? Simply removing those steps doesn't work.

Comment: Ok. Please post your source image or answer these few questions: do you use `imread` ? If so,  what is the output of `class(Img)` and `max(Img(:))` ?

Comment: Output of `class(img)` is logical & `max(Img(:))` : 1 [lmage Link](https://www.mediafire.com/?orzi18anfkkm11d)

Comment: ok, then you should use `BW = double(Img);` before finding the outer contour coordinates. I've edited my answer.